# Generic getter/setter in Dart?

Tags: dart, getter-setter, generic-programming

I need a generic way to access an object's property/getter.

In JavaScript this can be done via

```
const obj = {
    foo: 'Hello World',
    bar: 123
};

const propName = 'foo';
console.log(o[propName]); // "Hello World"
```

So, if I had a class in Dart, like the one below, how would I access a property in a generic way? Maybe with operator overloading or something?

```
class MyFooClass with ChangeNotifier {
  String _someText = 'Hello World';
  int _someNumber = 123;

  get someText => _someText;
  set someText(value) => _someText = value;

  get someNumber => _someNumber;
  set someNumber(value) => _someNumber = value;
}

var myFoo = MyFooClass();
print(myFoo['someText']); // The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'MyFooClass'
```

Comment: You can't.  You'd need to create a base class that specifies a `someText` getter as part of its interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using `dart:mirrors` (note that I have removed a few things to make it compile on its own):

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class MyFooClass {
  String _someText = 'Hello World';
  int _someNumber = 123;

  get someText => _someText;
  set someText(value) => _someText = value;

  get someNumber => _someNumber;
  set someNumber(value) => _someNumber = value;

  operator [](String name) {
    InstanceMirror i = reflect(this);

    for (DeclarationMirror declMirror in i.type.declarations.values) {
      if (declMirror.isPrivate) {
        continue;
      }

      Symbol simpleName = declMirror.simpleName;

      // It's not possible to get the name from a symbol directly: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28372
      if (simpleName.toString() == 'Symbol("${name}")') {
        return i.getField(simpleName).reflectee;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use it like:

```
void main() {
  var myFoo = MyFooClass();
  print(myFoo['someText']); // 'Hello, World!'
  print(myFoo['someNumber']); // 123
  print(myFoo['some non existent thing']); // null
}
```

---

## Old answer

Is this what you want?

```
void main() {
  var o = {'foo': 'Hello World', 'bar': 123};
  var propName = 'foo';

  print(o[propName]); // 'Hello World'
}
```

Comment: No, because I've got a concrete object from a concrete class.

Comment: Oh, I see you've updated the question. I don't have an answer ready at the moment, but will you be able to use `dart:mirrors`?

Comment: Well, this answer with `dart:mirrors` looks pretty neat, but as far as I read, the mirrors package can currently not be used in the stable branch, can it?

Comment: It can, but the docs say “The dart:mirrors library is unstable and its API might change slightly as a result of user feedback” :)